# Android firebase taking approx 30 second to load data first time

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is many same question available on Stackoerflow for the same issue.
But, not one have proper answer what i need.

**Problem:** 
I'm trying to load small data in my home screen from the firebase. But while i load it first time in app, it's take 20,30,40 seconds and some time it's take more then a minute.
if it's take 2 3 seconds then it's ok. but it's very big time to get connection or data from the firebase.

**What i need?**
I just need the solution of it to reduce this time.

Comment: How much data are you loading and how are you loading it? If you're loading images, it will take some time but text data should be very fast. Also, if your internet connection is slow, then Firebase will take longer to pull data

Comment: Please see the duplicate to understand why is this happening.